# How not to make delay while loading image?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am loading images from the server in a recyclerView and in parallel I am downloading that image too. What I actually want to do is that until image downloads until then show a blur or dark opaque preview of the image with progress bar on that.to load the image I am using glide and to download I am using `Okhttp`

**To load the image into view:-**

```
Glide.with(cont).load(modal.get(position).getMassege()).apply(requestOptions).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {

                        if(modal.get(position).getProgressPercentage()==0) {
                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    downloadFile(modal.get(position).getMassege(), position, modal.get(position).getMsgid(),modal.get(position).getTimeSent());

                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }).into(holder.image);
```

**To download image**

```
    public void downloadFile(String src, int position, String messageId,String timeStamp) {
    try {
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        String[] fileNam = src.split("/");
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(cont.getFilesDir() + fileNam[fileNam.length - 1]);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int progressPercentage = 0;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Constants.INTENT_FILTER);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.MESSAGE_POSITION_IN_CHAT_LIST, position);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.DOWNLOADING_FILE, true);

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            progressPercentage = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);
            if(progressPercentage==30||progressPercentage==60||progressPercentage==100) {
                intent.putExtra(Constants.PROGRESS, progressPercentage);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.FILE_PATH, cont.getFilesDir() + fileNam[fileNam.length - 1]);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.MESSAGE_ID, messageId);
                cont.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
            Log.d("Downloding" + progressPercentage, "Count" + count);
            if (progressPercentage > 99) {
                DatabaseHelperChattingToUsers databaseHelperChattingToUsers = new DatabaseHelperChattingToUsers(cont);
                String userId = databaseHelperChattingToUsers.getUserExists(sendTo);
                String splits[] = userId.split("/");
                databaseHelperChattingToUsers.updateContact(new ChattingToUsers(splits[0], sendTo, timeStamp, cont.getFilesDir() + fileNam[fileNam.length - 1],"0"));

                DatabaseHelper1 db = new DatabaseHelper1(cont);
                db.updateContact(messageId, "", "", "", 100);
                String filePath = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.FILE_PATH);
                db.updateChatMessage(messageId, filePath);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

**Where I have reached:**

I am able to download the image in parallel while loading image in recyclerView along with progress bar showing image download with blur preview of image.

**Problem I am facing:**

Image takes small time while loading in recyclerView for the blur preview of image but item view is added in the recyclerView and image loads in that after sometime

Comment: Trying enabling the cache in the glide

Comment: but on the first time it will still take time @Ümañgßürmån

Comment: Check out Glide.Thumnail()
http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html#thumbnail-requests

Comment: i have tried `thumbail(0.1f)` but no luck@LeoPelozo

Answer (score 0):

Glide would download image for you, why are you taking extra efforts by downloading it via `okHttp` ?

There will be always delay in downloading a complete image. It depends on your network speed and image size.

To reduce a delay you can **have different sizes of images stored on server**. On client side download small size image first and display it in recyclerview. ( *Smaller image size == less time to download*.)

Upon clicking row in recyclerview download the complete image by hitting another urls.

e.g.

https://www.example.com/images/small/image1.png ( 250x250 px = 100kb )

https://www.example.com/images/medium/image1.png ( 1000x1000 px = 400kb )

https://www.example.com/images/large/image1.png (3000x3000 ox = 1200kb)